# Lucene/Solr unexpected query answer

Tags: parsing, solr, lucene

I'm using Solr 4.4.0 running on Tomcat 7.0.29.
The solrconfig.xlm is as-delivered (excepted for the Solr home directory of course).
I could pass on the schema.xml, though I doubt this would help much, as the following will show.

If I select all documents containing "russia" in the text, which is the default field, ie if I execute the query "russia", I find only 1 document, which is correct.

If I select all documents containing "web" in the text  ("web"), the result is 29, which is also correct.

If I search for all documents that do not contain "russia" ("NOT(russia)"), the result is still correct (202).

If I search for all documents that contain "web" and do not contain "russia" ("web AND NOT(russia)"), the result is, once again, correct (28, because the document containing "russia" also contains "web").

But if I search for all documents that contain "web" or do not contain "russia" ("web OR NOT(russia)"), the result is still 28, though I should get 203 matches (the whole set).

Has anyone got an explanation ??

For information, the AND and OR work correctly if I don't use a NOT somewhere in the query, i.e. :
"web AND russia" --> OK
"web OR russia" --> OK

Comment: Add the text in the EDIT portion of your qn as an answer and accept your own answer. It makes the qn as answered (and an upvote on an answer gives you 10 instead of an upvote on a qn which gives you only 5 :), if you care for your rep, that is.).

Comment: There are some confusing cases with this sort of query, and the reason is that the boolean operators aren't really boolean operators, but rather get translated into `MUST`/`SHOULD`/`MUST_NOT` clauses, which is how Lucene queries really work.  I recommend using the +/- prefix operators for lucene queries if at all possible, to avoid confusion, and make more effective use of Lucene functionality.  See this great article: [Why Not AND, OR, And NOT?](http://searchhub.org/2011/12/28/why-not-and-or-and-not/) for more complete information on the topic.

Comment: OK, thanks arun, I just did so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution from Yonik Seeley, which is to translate the NOT(russia) into (*:* -russia), so that a positive value (*:* i.e. all documents) can be used to substract from (-russia). This solution works very well. I still believe that it would be a good idea to modify the parser so that the strainghtforward request "web OR NOT(russia)" would work without translation.